# Beta function of two copies of the same model with interactions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, interactions, effective-field-theory

I have a particular model with two couplings, let's call it model A, for which I have the set of beta functions and fixed points. Now I am interested in a model where I have two copies of model A, each with a different fundamental field, let's call that model B.
So, model B has two couplings for each field plus a fifth interaction that couples the two fields. I know this might highly depend on the specific scenario, but is there a general strategy as to how one would obtain the beta functions of model B from the beta functions of model A?